# Using a frameset for a web app

Tags: html

I am working on a web app consisting of 2 apps (one made by me, one 3rd party) residing side-by-side on one webpage. I have been using an `iframe` to embed the other app, but I want the size of the frame to be changed. Now, I could try going for a solution using javascript, but experience tells me, resizing in javascript is error-prone and inperformant. I am seriously considering to use a frameset in this case.

The arguments against frames I have seen so far do not apply to my case in the slightest, nobody wants to bookmark only a part of the page, the 3rd party app can be accessed externally anyways.

Now, I am wondering how bad the idea of using a `frameset` really is, I think I saw it being deprecated in the future, meaning support for it could be lost in near future? What other alternatives are there?

Comment: Frames are already deprecated, this is 2014. Use CSS instead.

Comment: @CBroe that was however, what I gathered from the things I read; Additionally, HTML5 supports iframes...

Comment: @TheBlueDog The CSS resize property does not do what I intend and has very bad support as of now.